# Access HTTP authentication username in PHP?

Tags: php, http, digest-authentication

Is it possible in PHP to access the login name of a user authenticated with server's native HTTP digest authentication (as **starkly opposed** to a PHP implementation of the same HTTP authentication protocol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are after is provided in the HTTP header sent from the client (as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617 ), namely the header `Authorization`.

In PHP this header can be retrieved like so:

```
$header = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
```

The header contains a number of key value pairs separated by commas. The username is in the `username` key, you can extract this by something like:

```
preg_match('/username="([^"]+)"/', $header, $matches);
$username = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out in the meantime (accepting still). The confounding factor was that I mistakenly believed the digest auth to have been set up for the document root while it was only set up for a subdir. The component I was working on, residing in another subdir, obviously did not get the Authorization header.